# SQLCMD При входе в систему пользователя произошла ошибка

Tags: sql, sql-server

Написал инструкцию для sqlcmd и выполнил его в командной строке:
sqlcmd.exe -S "ANVAR\SQLEXPRESS" -d ZKZS -U КАВ -P 0 -i "C:\Users\anvar\Downloads\Testing Access.sql" -o "C:\Users\anvar\OneDrive\Базы Данных\Курсовая\Управление доступом\Testing Login МВА.txt"

Открываю Testing Login МВА.txt, а там написано:
Sqlcmd: ошибка - Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server: При входе в систему пользователя "КАВ" произошла ошибка..
Пользователь и его пароль правильные

Comment: Попробуйте записать в кавычках пароль и юзера. При условии что данный пароль верен для юзера и он существует

Comment: как я понимаю юзер и пароль без кавычек пишется, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Остаётся проверить доступ данного юзера к данной базе данных